# Tikz crashes with vertical lines in plot - Error: Dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

I had to shorten the code because it would not fit here. I am trying to make 4 subplots in Tikz. I used Matlab and Matlab2Tikz to get the figure in Latex. I cannot compile and keep getting an error message saying dimensions are too large. In general I cannot compile when I have vertical lines in a plot. It seems to work if I do not plot vertical lines around the edges. But even after doing this I cannot get this to run. I tried using logaxis but it does not work. I can see that the numerical precision might be an issue. Is there any way I can upload the whole code (41,000 characters).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength\figH
\newlength\figW
\setlength{\figH}{14cm}
\setlength{\figW}{14cm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.411\figW,
height=0.419\figH,
at={(0\figW,0.581\figH)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={white!15!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xmin=1.995,
xmax=2.002,
xtick={1.995,1.996,1.997,1.998,1.999,2,2.001,2.002},
every outer y axis line/.append style={white!15!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ymin=0.4972,
ymax=0.4988,
ytick={0.4968,0.497085714285714,0.497371428571429,0.497657142857143,0.497942857142857,0.498228571428571,0.498514285714286,0.4988},
yticklabels={{0.4974},{0.4977},{0.4979},{0.4982},{0.4985},{0.4988}},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Leverage - $\omega$ menu - 1st case},
axis on top
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,line width=3.0pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   0.00405480160460175\\
1.05    0.0487783607094429\\
1.1 0.0903673139868394\\
1.15    0.129000385076014\\
1.2 0.164856297616192\\
1.25    0.198113775246594\\
1.3 0.228951541606446\\
1.35    0.257548320334969\\
1.4 0.284082835071388\\
1.45    0.308733809454926\\
1.5 0.331679967124806\\
1.55    0.353100031720252\\
1.6 0.37317138790318\\
1.65    0.39203679702767\\
1.7 0.409806420548708\\
1.75    0.426579957979414\\
1.8 0.442446767924539\\
1.85    0.457487093795261\\
1.9 0.471773046254589\\
1.95    0.485369454814126\\
2   0.498334622058237\\
2.05    0.510721000914645\\
2.1 0.52257580672137\\
2.15    0.533941571074948\\
2.2 0.544856642127527\\
2.25    0.555355635066074\\
2.3 0.565469836254727\\
2.35    0.575227564528552\\
2.4 0.584654493182163\\
2.45    0.593773936202264\\
2.5 0.602607102220926\\
2.55    0.611173319521002\\
2.6 0.619490235223824\\
2.65    0.627573991552496\\
2.7 0.635439381809878\\
2.75    0.643099988452892\\
2.8 0.650568305394417\\
2.85    0.657855846427376\\
2.9 0.664973241446634\\
2.95    0.671930321944941\\
3   0.678736197079697\\
3.05    0.685399321447306\\
3.1 0.691927555560306\\
3.15    0.698328219897672\\
3.2 0.704608143289324\\
3.25    0.710773706300213\\
3.3 0.716830880195881\\
3.35    0.72278526199867\\
3.4 0.728642106080454\\
3.45    0.734406352682699\\
3.5 0.740082653706761\\
3.55    0.745675396075622\\
3.6 0.751188722932027\\
3.65    0.756626552906371\\
3.7 0.761992597660164\\
3.75    0.767290377886879\\
3.8 0.772523237931033\\
3.85    0.777694359168023\\
3.9 0.782806772271205\\
3.95    0.787863368478654\\
4   0.792866909959752\\
4.05    0.797820039370921\\
4.1 0.802725288680321\\
4.15    0.807585087332991\\
4.2 0.812401769820542\\
4.25    0.817177582713024\\
4.3 0.821914691204866\\
4.35    0.826615185221763\\
4.4 0.831281085130888\\
4.45    0.835914347092908\\
4.5 0.840516868090767\\
4.55    0.845090490667171\\
4.6 0.84963700739996\\
4.65    0.854158165142206\\
4.7 0.858655669051742\\
4.75    0.863131186433027\\
4.8 0.867586350412615\\
4.85    0.872022763468134\\
4.9 0.87644200082947\\
4.95    0.880845613769834\\
5   0.885235132803554\\
5.05    0.889612070806723\\
5.1 0.893977926076298\\
5.15    0.89833418534284\\
5.2 0.90268232675182\\
5.25    0.907023822828274\\
5.3 0.911360143439611\\
5.35    0.915692758771521\\
5.4 0.920023142332188\\
5.45    0.924352774000494\\
5.5 0.928683143134431\\
5.55    0.933015751756753\\
5.6 0.937352117835778\\
5.65    0.941693778680454\\
5.7 0.946042294470084\\
5.75    0.95039925194078\\
5.8 0.95476626825252\\
5.85    0.959144995062944\\
5.9 0.963537122836488\\
5.95    0.967944385420459\\
6   0.972368564923035\\
6.05    0.976811496932123\\
6.1 0.98127507611857\\
6.15    0.985761262272532\\
6.2 0.990272086827917\\
6.25    0.994809659936966\\
6.3 0.99937617816532\\
6.35    1.00397393288761\\
6.4 1.00860531947489\\
6.45    1.0132728473786\\
6.5 1.01797915123107\\
6.55    1.02272700310144\\
6.6 1.02751932606699\\
6.65    1.03235920928632\\
6.7 1.03724992479113\\
6.75    1.04219494625035\\
6.8 1.04719797000459\\
6.85    1.05226293872207\\
6.9 1.05739406809184\\
6.95    1.06259587704886\\
7   1.06787322212149\\
7.05    1.07323133661068\\
7.1 1.07867587545612\\
7.15    1.08421296682763\\
7.2 1.0898492717074\\
7.25    1.0955920530175\\
7.3 1.10144925621185\\
7.35    1.10742960371964\\
7.4 1.11354270623065\\
7.45    1.11979919459681\\
7.5 1.12621087715541\\
7.55    1.13279092864467\\
7.6 1.13955411871401\\
7.65    1.1465170905136\\
7.7 1.15369870325595\\
7.75    1.16112045738489\\
7.8 1.16880702768564\\
7.85    1.17678693928326\\
7.9 1.18509343552524\\
7.95    1.19376560767815\\
8   1.20284988825752\\
};
\addplot [color=black,dotted,line width=0.5pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
2   0.4973\\
2   0.497310357142857\\
2   0.497320714285714\\
2   0.497331071428571\\
2   0.497341428571429\\
2   0.497351785714286\\
2   0.497362142857143\\
2   0.4973725\\
2   0.497382857142857\\
2   0.497393214285714\\
2   0.497403571428571\\
2   0.497413928571429\\
2   0.497424285714286\\
2   0.497434642857143\\
2   0.497445\\
2   0.497455357142857\\
2   0.497465714285714\\
2   0.497476071428571\\
2   0.497486428571429\\
2   0.497496785714286\\
2   0.497507142857143\\
2   0.4975175\\
2   0.497527857142857\\
2   0.497538214285714\\
2   0.497548571428571\\
2   0.497558928571429\\
2   0.497569285714286\\
2   0.497579642857143\\
2   0.49759\\
2   0.497600357142857\\
2   0.497610714285714\\
2   0.497621071428571\\
2   0.497631428571429\\
2   0.497641785714286\\
2   0.497652142857143\\
2   0.4976625\\
2   0.497672857142857\\
2   0.497683214285714\\
2   0.497693571428571\\
2   0.497703928571429\\
2   0.497714285714286\\
2   0.497724642857143\\
2   0.497735\\
2   0.497745357142857\\
2   0.497755714285714\\
2   0.497766071428571\\
2   0.497776428571429\\
2   0.497786785714286\\
2   0.497797142857143\\
2   0.4978075\\
2   0.497817857142857\\
2   0.497828214285714\\
2   0.497838571428571\\
2   0.497848928571429\\
2   0.497859285714286\\
2   0.497869642857143\\
2   0.49788\\
2   0.497890357142857\\
2   0.497900714285714\\
2   0.497911071428571\\
2   0.497921428571429\\
2   0.497931785714286\\
2   0.497942142857143\\
2   0.4979525\\
2   0.497962857142857\\
2   0.497973214285714\\
2   0.497983571428571\\
2   0.497993928571429\\
2   0.498004285714286\\
2   0.498014642857143\\
2   0.498025\\
2   0.498035357142857\\
2   0.498045714285714\\
2   0.498056071428571\\
2   0.498066428571429\\
2   0.498076785714286\\
2   0.498087142857143\\
2   0.4980975\\
2   0.498107857142857\\
2   0.498118214285714\\
2   0.498128571428571\\
2   0.498138928571429\\
2   0.498149285714286\\
2   0.498159642857143\\
2   0.49817\\
2   0.498180357142857\\
2   0.498190714285714\\
2   0.498201071428571\\
2   0.498211428571429\\
2   0.498221785714286\\
2   0.498232142857143\\
2   0.4982425\\
2   0.498252857142857\\
2   0.498263214285714\\
2   0.498273571428571\\
2   0.498283928571429\\
2   0.498294285714286\\
2   0.498304642857143\\
2   0.498315\\
2   0.498325357142857\\
2   0.498335714285714\\
2   0.498346071428571\\
2   0.498356428571429\\
2   0.498366785714286\\
2   0.498377142857143\\
2   0.4983875\\
2   0.498397857142857\\
2   0.498408214285714\\
2   0.498418571428571\\
2   0.498428928571429\\
2   0.498439285714286\\
2   0.498449642857143\\
2   0.49846\\
2   0.498470357142857\\
2   0.498480714285714\\
2   0.498491071428571\\
2   0.498501428571429\\
2   0.498511785714286\\
2   0.498522142857143\\
2   0.4985325\\
2   0.498542857142857\\
2   0.498553214285714\\
2   0.498563571428571\\
2   0.498573928571429\\
2   0.498584285714286\\
2   0.498594642857143\\
2   0.498605\\
2   0.498615357142857\\
2   0.498625714285714\\
2   0.498636071428571\\
2   0.498646428571429\\
2   0.498656785714286\\
2   0.498667142857143\\
2   0.4986775\\
2   0.498687857142857\\
2   0.498698214285714\\
2   0.498708571428571\\
2   0.498718928571429\\
2   0.498729285714286\\
2   0.498739642857143\\
2   0.49875\\
};
\addplot [color=black,dashed,line width=0.5pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1.9980558757947 0.4973\\
1.9980558757947 0.4976625\\
1.9980558757947 0.498025\\
1.9980558757947 0.4983875\\
1.9980558757947 0.49875\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor2,dashdotted,line width=0.5pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   0.497841641027983\\
1.05    0.497841641027983\\
1.1 0.497841641027983\\
1.15    0.497841641027983\\
1.2 0.497841641027983\\
1.25    0.497841641027983\\
1.3 0.497841641027983\\
1.35    0.497841641027983\\
1.4 0.497841641027983\\
1.45    0.497841641027983\\
1.5 0.497841641027983\\
1.55    0.497841641027983\\
1.6 0.497841641027983\\
1.65    0.497841641027983\\
1.7 0.497841641027983\\
1.75    0.497841641027983\\
1.8 0.497841641027983\\
1.85    0.497841641027983\\
1.9 0.497841641027983\\
1.95    0.497841641027983\\
2   0.497841641027983\\
2.05    0.497841641027983\\
2.1 0.497841641027983\\
2.15    0.497841641027983\\
2.2 0.497841641027983\\
2.25    0.497841641027983\\
2.3 0.497841641027983\\
2.35    0.497841641027983\\
2.4 0.497841641027983\\
2.45    0.497841641027983\\
2.5 0.497841641027983\\
2.55    0.497841641027983\\
2.6 0.497841641027983\\
2.65    0.497841641027983\\
2.7 0.497841641027983\\
2.75    0.497841641027983\\
2.8 0.497841641027983\\
2.85    0.497841641027983\\
2.9 0.497841641027983\\
2.95    0.497841641027983\\
3   0.497841641027983\\
3.05    0.497841641027983\\
3.1 0.497841641027983\\
3.15    0.497841641027983\\
3.2 0.497841641027983\\
3.25    0.497841641027983\\
3.3 0.497841641027983\\
3.35    0.497841641027983\\
3.4 0.497841641027983\\
3.45    0.497841641027983\\
3.5 0.497841641027983\\
3.55    0.497841641027983\\
3.6 0.497841641027983\\
3.65    0.497841641027983\\
3.7 0.497841641027983\\
3.75    0.497841641027983\\
3.8 0.497841641027983\\
3.85    0.497841641027983\\
3.9 0.497841641027983\\
3.95    0.497841641027983\\
4   0.497841641027983\\
4.05    0.497841641027983\\
4.1 0.497841641027983\\
4.15    0.497841641027983\\
4.2 0.497841641027983\\
4.25    0.497841641027983\\
4.3 0.497841641027983\\
4.35    0.497841641027983\\
4.4 0.497841641027983\\
4.45    0.497841641027983\\
4.5 0.497841641027983\\
4.55    0.497841641027983\\
4.6 0.497841641027983\\
4.65    0.497841641027983\\
4.7 0.497841641027983\\
4.75    0.497841641027983\\
4.8 0.497841641027983\\
4.85    0.497841641027983\\
4.9 0.497841641027983\\
4.95    0.497841641027983\\
5   0.497841641027983\\
5.05    0.497841641027983\\
5.1 0.497841641027983\\
5.15    0.497841641027983\\
5.2 0.497841641027983\\
5.25    0.497841641027983\\
5.3 0.497841641027983\\
5.35    0.497841641027983\\
5.4 0.497841641027983\\
5.45    0.497841641027983\\
5.5 0.497841641027983\\
5.55    0.497841641027983\\
5.6 0.497841641027983\\
5.65    0.497841641027983\\
5.7 0.497841641027983\\
5.75    0.497841641027983\\
5.8 0.497841641027983\\
5.85    0.497841641027983\\
5.9 0.497841641027983\\
5.95    0.497841641027983\\
6   0.497841641027983\\
6.05    0.497841641027983\\
6.1 0.497841641027983\\
6.15    0.497841641027983\\
6.2 0.497841641027983\\
6.25    0.497841641027983\\
6.3 0.497841641027983\\
6.35    0.497841641027983\\
6.4 0.497841641027983\\
6.45    0.497841641027983\\
6.5 0.497841641027983\\
6.55    0.497841641027983\\
6.6 0.497841641027983\\
6.65    0.497841641027983\\
6.7 0.497841641027983\\
6.75    0.497841641027983\\
6.8 0.497841641027983\\
6.85    0.497841641027983\\
6.9 0.497841641027983\\
6.95    0.497841641027983\\
7   0.497841641027983\\
7.05    0.497841641027983\\
7.1 0.497841641027983\\
7.15    0.497841641027983\\
7.2 0.497841641027983\\
7.25    0.497841641027983\\
7.3 0.497841641027983\\
7.35    0.497841641027983\\
7.4 0.497841641027983\\
7.45    0.497841641027983\\
7.5 0.497841641027983\\
7.55    0.497841641027983\\
7.6 0.497841641027983\\
7.65    0.497841641027983\\
7.7 0.497841641027983\\
7.75    0.497841641027983\\
7.8 0.497841641027983\\
7.85    0.497841641027983\\
7.9 0.497841641027983\\
7.95    0.497841641027983\\
8   0.497841641027983\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of inconsistencies, so it is very difficult (read *imposible*)  to figured out, what this graph should show. So far I can only say, that in data tables are most of values outside of `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` values. This cause error.

Comment: Regarding previous comment: if you comment `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` , you will get a graph, however then your defined ticks and ticks merge to one point on x and y axis ...

Comment: Zarko, thank you for pointing that out. I am relying on Matlab2tikz, so I just threw the code on Latex. I will try to use your suggestion.

Comment: Zarko, you are right: commenting or fixing the min and max values did the job. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by OP with help in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get after getting rid of most of the automatic options issued by matlab2tikz:
[image: pgfplots output]

```
\begin{axis}[%
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Leverage - $\omega$ menu - 1st case},
axis on top
]
...
\end{axis}
```

matlab2tikz is a great tool but cannot do miracles, always double check the options!